# Render layout without application layout in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render

I have a simple login form and a some other content which compose the rest of the application. My problem is I want to render the login form alone, then once the user has logged in he/she can see the rest of the app which is composed of the application layout.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another layout for the login and in the controller set like this at the top of your controller, specifying the actions that will use the other layout:

`layout "full_page", only: [sign_in, sign_up]`

Other option is to pass to the `render` method the `layout` option:

`render layout: "full_page"`

For more info check the Rails Guides

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render